# Find the number of all possibilities to visit all vertices once in a connected graph

Tags: algorithms, graphs, graph-traversal

Let $G$ be a connected undirected graph, e.g.:

```
u -- v -- w
 \  /
  x
```

I would like to determine the number of sequences in which every vertex of the graph is visited. This is supposed to work as follows:

- The starting vertex is fixed
- The next vertex to be visited must be an unvisited neighbor of one of the already visited vertices

The length of such a sequence is of course the number of vertices in $G$.

For the example above, the sequences starting from $x$ are:

- $ x \to u \to v \to w$
- $ x \to v \to u \to w $
- $ x \to v \to w \to u$

Therefore, the algorithm is supposed to yield $3$ as the output for $(G, x)$.

**Requirements:**

- I need an algorithm which I can actually apply in practice to *large* graphs ($n \geq 100,000$)
- I need a theoretical asymptotic run time

---

As a **follow-up question**: I need to calculate this quantity for all vertices as the starting vertex. Is there maybe a way to do this *efficiently*, i.e., to re-use information from one of the previous runs with different starting vertices?

Comment: What's the context for this question?  Where did you encounter it?  Or what is the motivation?  Is this a theoretical question where you are looking for the worst-case asymptotic running time, or a practical question where you have a specific graph and want an answer?  If practical, how large are your graphs?  What is the best algorithm you know of so far?  What requirements do you have on the running time?  Is an exponential time algorithm OK?

Comment: @D.W. I added some requirements as you desired. I could also give lots more context to this question but this would totally bloat my question I presume. But long story short I need this for a research project.

Comment: In directed acyclic graph, the above problem is [#P-complete](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/bf00383444).

Comment: @InuyashaYagami Thank you, this information is valuable to me. Do you think this result can be extended to more general graphs (i.e., *not* just DAGs)?

Comment: @Bob I have been trying to do the same. It is a good question. It seems a very fundamental problem but I couldn't find any known results on it.